# Shapefile field precision change python

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile

I have a shapefile where some columns from the attribute table of this shapefile have "Double" datatype with precision 15 (see below)

[image]

How can I change it to have precision 2 using Python?
For now I tried to do it via geopandas as follows:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(path)
gdf.hght = gdf.hght.round(2)
```

The values shrink, but precision stays the same.

upd the `print(gdf.hght)` shows the following: `Name: hght, Length: 56967, dtype: float64`

Comment: Here is how do to this with QGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110105/35561

Comment: thank you but I need via python, not via qgis interface

Comment: You may have a column indicating that the values are double, Qstring, qlonglong, etc. but the values themselves can in fact be a different datatype. In this case, it looks as you dtype may be integers?

Comment: Could you please `print(gdf.hght)` and show the data type? Should receive your index and hght column attached with a `Name:`, and `dtype:`

Comment: I would suggest doing `gdf['hght'] = gdf['hght'].astype('float')` and then use this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378389/pandas-data-frame-change-float-format-keep-type-float) for specifying precision

Comment: @МаринаЛисниченко You can try using pyqgis. I don't think you can change the existing field's precision, but you can try creating a new field with qgis.core.QgsField https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Field/QgsField.html